# Can I have an alias within the subquery and run the avg of this alias?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I keep getting an error when I run this query. It keeps saying that total_ABC is not found in the tables a,b,c, or d. This is within the subquery though. How can I make this work?

```
SELECT AVG(total_ABC)/3600
FROM database.office a
INNER JOIN database.activation b ON a.gk = b.gk AND installment_description = 'FRIENDS'
INNER JOIN database.releases c ON a.release_key = c.release_key AND DESCRIPTION = 'PHEOBEBUFFAY'
INNER JOIN database.usercode d ON a.user_key = d.user_key AND PLAYED_DATE >= 20200319  
WHERE action_date_key BETWEEN 20200319 AND 20200324 and user_key in
                  (SELECT user_key, SUM(daily_playtime_value) AS total_ABC
                   FROM database.time e
                   WHERE game_key = 1
                   AND date_key > 20200324
                    GROUP BY 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT AVG(x.total_ABC)/3600
FROM database.office a INNER JOIN
     database.activation b
     ON a.gk = b.gk AND installment_description = 'FRIENDS' INNER JOIN 
     database.releases c
     ON a.release_key = c.release_key AND DESCRIPTION = 'PHEOBEBUFFAY'
INNER JOIN
     database.usercode d
     ON a.user_key = d.user_key AND PLAYED_DATE >= 20200319 JOIN
     (SELECT user_key, SUM(daily_playtime_value) AS total_ABC
      FROM database.time e
      WHERE game_key = 1 AND date_key > 20200324
      GROUP BY 1
     ) x
     USING (user_key)
WHERE action_date_key BETWEEN 20200319 AND 20200324 ;
```

Two further suggestions:

- Use *meaningful* table aliases, usually abbreviations for the tables.  The query is just hard to understand with `a` standing for "office" and `b` standing for "activation".  These should be `o` and `a` respectively.
- Qualify all column names so it is clear where the columns come from.